# Is there a way to trigger a stored procedure at the end of all the insert/delete on an entity

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, triggers

My application is using Entity frame work and There is one table called t_details which holds multiple records. When the application gets saved, this entity gets deleted and added.

I also have a sql Db trigger on this table that gets executed when an insert/delete happens on this table. Since entity is deleting each entry one by one and inserting it one by one, it triggers the Db trigger every instance of a delete or insert and the performance becomes slow.

Is there a way I can initiate the trigger just once after all the delete and once at the end of all inserts.

Trigger is created as below now

```
Create TRIGGER test.trigger_Data
   ON  test.t_details
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

    EXEC [test].[spu_call_details]  -- this in turn will call some views/tables etc.
END
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the appropriate database that you are using. You need `statement level trigger` but the answer depends on the database that you are using.

Comment: @Popeye: the data base is sql server

Comment: Not saying I have a solution either way, but out of curiosity how would the database know which delete/insert was the last?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError : Ya, thats were I am kind of stuck.

Comment: You are looking at this "issue" from the wrong perspective. Your application code performs a task (application gets saved?), it and only it has the context - not your trigger and not the database engine. Your code belongs with this "event".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do what you want without modifying the application.  In SQL Server, triggers are *statement* level.

Here are some options:

- Change the application to do all the deletes in a single statement.  Then the trigger will be executed once for the transaction.
- Change the application to indicate the end of a batch -- perhaps with an update on some table indicating the last time.  Then use that for your trigger.
- You could play games with an event queue.  Instead of running the code, you could schedule it to run in, say, one minute.  Then don't run the code if another delete has occurred in that time frame.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only concerned with tracking this when records are added/updated/deleted by your application then you could leverage bounded contexts to action this on the applicable DbContext's SaveChanges:

Start by creating a separate DbContext that will service this Stored Procedure call or interact with the desired entities to track records for the changes. Create a reference to this DbContext as part of your application DbContext where you want to track the entity updates.

So as an example, a LoggingDbContext and an AppDbContext:

```
public class LoggingDbContext : DbContext
{
  // ...
}

public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly LoggingDbContext _loggingDbContext = null;
    public AppDbContext(string connectionString, LoggingDbContext loggingDbContext)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        _loggingDbContext = loggingDbContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("loggingDbContext");
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        // Do your logging call...
        var log = new Log { Message = "SaveChanges Called!" };
        _loggingDbContext.Logs.Add(log);
        _loggingDbContext.SaveChanges();

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

That `OnSaveChanges` override can call your stored procedure or whatever is necessary. If you want to differentiate between when entities are added, removed, etc. you can use the ChangeTracker to inspect the changes for particular change types or specific entities:

```
var updatedCustomers = ChangeTracker.Entries()
    .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified)
    .Select(x => x.Entity)
    .OfType<Customer>();

var insertedCustomers = ChangeTracker.Entries()
    .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added)
    .Select(x => x.Entity)
    .OfType<Customer>();

var deletedCustomers = ChangeTracker.Entries()
    .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Deleted)
    .Select(x => x.Entity)
    .OfType<Customer>();
```

From there you could inspect the entities with `.ToList()` or `.Select()` for particular details, or just do a `.Any()` or `.Count()` to assess whether a particular entity type was added/updated/removed etc.

I use this pattern in my DbContexts for models that track things like LastModifiedBy user/date tracking. I have a CurrentUserLocator for resolving the currently logged in user for the session then a base class for "editable" entities which contains the CreatedBy/CreatedAt/LastModifiedBy/LastModifiedAt fields. This way as my DbContext saves details the Context `SaveChanges` looks like this:

```
// These DbContexts do not allow for hard Deletes. 
if (ChangeTracker.Entries().Any(x => x.State == EntityState.Deleted))
    throw new ApplicationException("Hard deletes are not supported.");

var currentUser = Users.Single(x => x.UserId == CurrentUserLocator.CurrentUserId); 
var updatedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
    .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified)
    .Select(x => x.Entity)
    .Cast<EditableEntityBase>();
foreach (var entity in updatedEntities)
{
    entity.LastModifiedBy = currentUser;
    entity.LastModifiedAt = DateTime.Now;
}

var insertedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
    .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added)
    .Select(x => x.Entity)
    .Cast<EditableEntityBase>();
foreach (var entity in insertedEntities)
{
    entity.CreatedBy = entity.LastModifiedBy = currentUser;
    entity.CreatedAt = entity.LastModifiedAt = DateTime.Now;
}

return base.SaveChanges();
```

The context also tracks non-editable entities (lookups etc.) so this also helps guard against situations where somehow a non-editable entity gets inserted or updated. Since my system uses soft-deletes in this example it also guards against hard-deleting entities. This approach can be used to leverage a separate DbContext to call a Stored Procedure or otherwise modify other entities etc. without "tripping" on those change tracking hooks in `SaveChanges`.